# What modes does git pull have other than the default?

Tags: git, git-pull

The `git-pull` section of the [Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull/2.21.0) says "In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD."

What other modes are there, and where can I find documentation for them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other modes are described in the documentation you linked.

The word *mode* is not very well defined, so it means different things to different people.  Probably the primary item is somewhat well disguised here, about 1/4 of the way down the page:

> `-r`
>   `--rebase[=false|true|merges|preserve|interactive]`
>
> When true, rebase the current branch on top of the upstream branch after fetching. If there is a remote-tracking branch corresponding to the upstream branch and the upstream branch was rebased since last fetched, the rebase uses that information to avoid rebasing non-local changes.
>
> When set to `merges`, rebase using `git rebase --rebase-merges` so that the local merge commits are included in the rebase (see [git-rebase[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for details).
>
> When set to preserve, rebase with the `--preserve-merges` option passed to `git rebase` so that locally created merge commits will not be flattened.
>
> When false, merge the current branch into the upstream branch.
>
> When `interactive`, enable the interactive mode of rebase.
>
> See `pull.rebase`, `branch.<name>.rebase` and `branch.autoSetupRebase` in [git-config[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) if you want to make `git pull` always use `--rebase` instead of merging.
>
>   Note
>   This is a potentially dangerous mode of operation. It rewrites history, which does not bode well when you published that history already. Do
>   **not**
>   use this option unless you have read
>   [git-rebase[1]]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)
>   carefully.

However, other "modes" may include running `git pull` with arguments, such as `git pull upstream branch-X`.  This runs `git fetch upstream branch-X` followed by running `git merge FETCH_HEAD`, so to me that seems like the same "mode".

Personally, I recommend not using `git pull` at all.  Run `git fetch`, then run your own second command.  I find, for instance, that I often want to run `git log` *between* the two commands, and using `git pull` makes that impossible.  I may choose `git merge`, or `git rebase`, or neither, after seeing what `git fetch` fetched.

Answer (score 1):

> When false, merge the current branch into the upstream branch.

Warning: this is incorrect.

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), documentation fix for "[`git pull --rebase=no`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e9fe413fc29efac6d223cf1bd0cad10231e37df3/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--r))</sup>".

See [commit d3236be](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3236bececc24d4b8ddc736d278ce0d3d5ff12d6) (21 Jul 2021) by [Felipe Contreras (`felipec`)](https://github.com/felipec).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e9fe413](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e9fe413fc29efac6d223cf1bd0cad10231e37df3), 02 Aug 2021)</sup>

> ### [`doc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3236bececc24d4b8ddc736d278ce0d3d5ff12d6): pull: fix rebase=false documentation
>
> <sup>Cc: Stephen Haberman</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Felipe Contreras</sup>
> <sup>[jc: updated the log message]</sup>

> "[`git pull --rebase=false`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3236bececc24d4b8ddc736d278ce0d3d5ff12d6/Documentation/git-pull.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--r))</sup> means we merge their history into ours, but it has been described the other way around.

`git pull` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3236bececc24d4b8ddc736d278ce0d3d5ff12d6/Documentation/git-pull.txt#L120):

> When false, merge the upstream branch into the current branch.

(instead of:
When false, merge the current branch into the upstream branch.)